# Saving Data after closing page

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm new to java and this may seem like a stupid question, but nevertheless. I'm creating a system using Netbeans GUI and wanted to know how to save the data once you leave the page. I have 4 GUI pages and each time I navigate to another page it doesn't save the data for that particular page.

Comment: I don't know Netbeans GUI, but normally you can register event listeners to react on change/leave page events.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you that use javascript instead java. You can use localStorage, SessionStorage and HTML5 DB to save all your data.

Depending on your case and situation, one or other could be useful.

LocalStorage is permament, session storage is http session oriented

HTML5 DB is database oriented, so is for more complex applications

Hope it helps, cheers!